# Amazon CloudFront vs ExpressVPN

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, vpn, nsurldownload

We have Mac and Windows apps that access online data files frequently. These are used for weather and earthquake data, among other things. Our files are hosted on a Amazon CloudFront distribution backed by an S3 bucket.

Recently, people who are using ExpressVPN on Macs are getting 403 errors and "ClientHungUpRequest" results from CloudFront.

On the Mac side, we are using `NSURLSession` and everything works fine without ExpressVPN.

Is there anything we can do about this, or is Amazon doing something to block ExpressVPN IPs from being able to access our hosted files?

Comment: Have You managed to resolve Your issue ? I'm running onto the same problem lately.

Comment: I have not seen this error in some time and never heard anything about it on Amazon's forums either. I suspect it is something on Amazon's end... possibly intentional, but I don't know.

Comment: I am continuing to see this error (but for much more than just ExpressVPN users)! Would greatly appreciate some AWS expert help resolving this...